# How to set homepage route url using angular routing?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I have only one route in my application so when application starts i want to show route as `http://localhost:4200/specialtyQ` for some reason now application is not loading i have below code to achieve that , How i can show correct url ?

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '/specialtyQs',
  component: AppComponent
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add one default route to redirect

```
const routes: Routes = [{
   path: 'specialtyQs',
   component: AppComponent
 },
 {
   path: '',
   redirectTo: 'specialtyQs',
   pathMatch: 'full'
 }];
```

This will redirect to specific url.

Comment: Worked Thank you Sir!

Comment: actually just noticed page is showing twice in the browser including navbar

Comment: you mean double content? can you add a screenshot?

Comment: asked new questions and added image there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61126591/page-is-showing-twice-in-the-browser-using-angular-router

Answer (score 0):

Just add a routing path like below in your code instead of the way you have added it.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/specialtyQs',
  pathMatch: 'full'
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: this is not changing anything url is still `http://localhost:4200/` it should change to `http://localhost:4200/specialtyQs` and we did not specified component as i wanted to load appComponent as default

Comment: let me create a stackblitz instance for you.