# page is showing twice in the browser using angular router?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-ui-router

Angular was loading page on default port `localhost:4200` i wanted it to serve as `localhost:4200/specialtyquestions` when app build and that is working but its showing pages twice in the browser , Any idea what is implemented wrong here ?

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'specialtyquestions',
  component: AppComponent
},
{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: 'specialtyquestions',
  pathMatch: 'full'
}];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <app-create-questions></app-create-questions>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <div class="row">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-backdrop='static' (click)="openModal()" style="margin-top: 300px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">Start Formatting</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <app-format-questions></app-format-questions>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<h2>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</h2>
```

image

[image]

Comment: Can you paste the html also?

Comment: @GouravGarg added html

Comment: i guess i have to remove router-outlet in this case ?

Comment: Yes you should, you don't need that.

Answer (score 1):

Remove Router-Outlet 
because when you Add that tag at the last it Run that part again. so remove that part from the end and Check

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <app-create-questions></app-create-questions>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <div class="row">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-backdrop='static' (click)="openModal()" style="margin-top: 300px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">Start Formatting</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <app-format-questions></app-format-questions>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Router part is needed when you want to route from one page to another 
e.x. 127.0.0.1:4000/Student

Comment: if i add more pages which will have different route then i would need to add router outlet back in app.component.html and it will show appComponent pages twice again no ?

Comment: Then you have to modify your little bit of code the things which is prefix that only you can hold on app.component.ts and for other thing you can make another component